# CSS - Understanding child selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

could anyone explain the difference between these two?

```
p a {
  color: red;
}

p > a {
  color: red;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Anyone" is in this case the [official CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators), that does it best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'p a' will select all 'a' elements that are contained within a p element (descendents), even if they are not immediate children.

'p>a' will only select immediate children of p that are also 'a' elements.

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/a9mfbbax/

HTML:

```
<p>
    <a>CHILD A1</a>
    <span><a>DESCENDENT A2</a></span>
    <a>CHILD A3</a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
/* DESCENDENTS WILL BE RED */
p a{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

/* CHILDREN WILL BE BLUE */
p>a {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white
}
```

See [W3C Schools CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Not sure, but I've updated my answer to include a fiddle to play around with, hope it helps.